# Spring Hibernate, GET Query, Hibernate Query is formed successfully and I'm able to get data from DB, But when i hit from Browser its throwing 404

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am currently learning Spring with Hibernate..
I have a simple Customer table where columns are "ID", "first_name", "last_name", "email"..

I use hibernate to query the database and list the result of all customers as output..
I have used Spring boot along with MVC for the same..

The problem is I am able to fetch data from DB successfully and able to print in console.. But when I try to access it through browser by a GET request, Its throwing a 404 ERROR..

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate.mapping.onetoone</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hibernate.mapping.onetoone</name>
    <description>Demo project for Hibernate One to One</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/c3p0/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1.2</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
enter code here
enter code here
```

and My SpringMain Application Class

```
package com.example.hibernate.crud;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.example.hibernate.crud.*")
@EntityScan("com.example.hibernate.crud.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:persistence-mysql.properties"})
public class HibernateApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HibernateApplication.class, args);


    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource myDataSource() {
         // create connection pool
         ComboPooledDataSource myDataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
         // set the jdbc driver
         try {
             myDataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
         }
         catch (PropertyVetoException exc) {
             throw new RuntimeException(exc);
         }

         // set database connection props
            myDataSource.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
            myDataSource.setUser(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
            myDataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
         // set connection pool props
            myDataSource.setInitialPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.initialPoolSize")));
            myDataSource.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.minPoolSize")));
            myDataSource.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxPoolSize")));
            myDataSource.setMaxIdleTime(Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("connection.pool.maxIdleTime")));
         return myDataSource;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {

         Properties props = new Properties();
         props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
         props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
         return props;
    } 

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
     // create session factorys
         LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
         // set the properties
         sessionFactory.setDataSource(myDataSource());
         sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("hibernate.packagesToScan"));
         sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
         return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {

     // setup transaction manager based on session factory

     HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
     txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
     return txManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry
     .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
     .addResourceLocations("WEB-INF/resources/");
    }

}
```

And My Controller class

```
package com.example.hibernate.crud.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.hibernate.crud.DAO.CustomerDAO;
import com.example.hibernate.crud.entity.Customer;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Customer> getStudentList() {

        return customerDAO.getAllCustomers();
    }

}
```

And my Entity Class

```
package com.example.hibernate.crud.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    public Customer() {

    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }



}
```

And My DAO Interface:

```
package com.example.hibernate.crud.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.hibernate.crud.entity.Customer;

public interface CustomerDAO {

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers();

}
```

My DAO Implementation class:

```
package com.example.hibernate.crud.DAO;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.example.hibernate.crud.entity.Customer;

@Repository
public class CustomerDAOImpl implements CustomerDAO {

    @Autowired SessionFactory sessionfactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {

        Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();


            System.out.println("REACHED UNTIL THIS..,");

            Query<Customer> query = session.createQuery("from Customer", Customer.class);

            //session.getTransaction().commit();

            for(Customer c : query.getResultList()) {
                System.out.println("REACHED LOOP");
                System.out.println(c);
            }

            return query.getResultList();

    }

}
```

My properties file:

```
#
# JDBC connection properties
#
jdbc.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_customer_tracker?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
jdbc.user=root
jdbc.password=
#
# Connection pool properties
#
connection.pool.initialPoolSize=5
connection.pool.minPoolSize=5
connection.pool.maxPoolSize=20
connection.pool.maxIdleTime=3000
#
# Hibernate properties
#
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.packagesToScan=com.example.hibernate.crud.entity
```

And when I run My application and hit following URL **"http://localhost:8080/student/list"** in browser I get the following Log in console:

[The Console output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orO9o.png)

**As you can see from the logs the data is fetched from DB and printed in the console..
But when in the browser it is returning 404 as follows**

[THE browser Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD6Vw.png)

***Couldnt understand why it happens.. Please clarify..***

Attaching DB model for reference:
[DB Model image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAI6o.png)

Comment: Did you check are your getting any exception in console ?

Comment: @Eklavya i am not getting exception in console
i have attached console output as image link in the question itself.. please refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it the problem is most likely your controller. You have annotated your controller with @Controller instead of a @RestController. 
Look into this [article](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/08/difference-restcontroller-controller-annotation-spring-mvc-rest.html);

> The job of the @Controller is to create a Map of model object and find
>   a view but the @RestController simply returns the object and object
>   data is directly written into HTTP response as JSON or XML.

So basically you can do two of the following:
1. Add @ResponseBody annotation to your getStudentList method;
2. Annotate controller class with @RestController

hope this helps.

Comment: Have done the changes suggested by you..Now getting empty result in browser

Comment: Can you log list results in your controller method before its returned? Also try checking request in your browser's network tab.

Comment: I have logged the result .. I have posted the link for cnsole out put in the question itself.. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/orO9o.png

Please refer the link.. The output is printed

Comment: Well i took a look at your customer entity and it seems you dont have setters and getters. Why this is important is that spring-boot uses jackson to convert your reponses in JSON structure. And for jacskons to do so, your entity/dto class needs to have either: 
1. public fields
2. public getters;

Comment: Try adding setters and getters to your Customer class. and check again.

Comment: you are Welomce!